# How can I cache specific object inside array in redis laravel then return the cache together with the array

Tags: arrays, laravel, redis

I need to store specific object from array and retrieve it together with the other object inside array.

```
 $data= array(
["apple", "red"],
["banana", "yellow"],
["orange", "orange"],
)
$cache = {
 [fruit:"banana", color:"yellow"],
 [fruit:"apple", color:"red"]//from cached in redis,
 [fruit:"orange", color:"yellow"],
}
return $cached
```

Comment: What have you tried, and why isn't it working for you? Laravel has great cache documentation here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/cache

Comment: I'm using redis to cache array but I want to cache each object inside an array

Comment: Your example seems confusing, can you come with an code example using Cache::get() and Cache::put() and what you would expect?